# how to maintain the fragment depend upon back button?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a navigation drawer. In that navigation drawer I've got five fragments. When I select a fragment, it shows up. When I press the back button, it goes to the previous fragment. However, I need the back button to send you back to the first fragment. How do I do this?

Comment: you mean to ask when you back press on any fragments like F2 or F3 or F4 or F5 you must be direct to F1,right? Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwrite the `onBackPressed()` method in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentTransactionn ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace([your fragment container], yourfirstFragment, TAG_FRAGMENTFIRST);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Even though this does answer the question, it gives the problem that users won't be able to close the app by using the back-button.

Comment: Yes, I know. But implementing this behaviour should be easy. If you like, you can improve my code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you already figured out how to show fragments. I'd suggest using the same code you use in your navigation drawer in the `public void onBackPressed()` to draw up the first fragment again. To make users able to exit the app, check if the first fragment is already visible. If so, call `super.onBackPressed()` or `finish()`.